# How to display variable from local storage as soon as page loads. JQuery/JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have successfully placed a variable in local storage I am now trying to display that variable as soon as the next page loads, I am unsure of how to get this script to execute as soon as the page transitions.

My code is as follows

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#home").on('pageinit ', function() {


            //alert('pageinit');
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="Name: " +localStorage.userName;            

      });

  </script>
  </head><!-- Main Page -->

  <div id="home" data-role="page" data-title="home">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
    </div>
  <!-- /header -->

  <div data-role="content">

    <div id='customer'> Customer Name </div>
    <p id="output"></p>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Alarm</a> <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Reports</a> <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Summary</a> </div>
  <!-- /content -->

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-bar"> <a href="index.html" data-role="button" >Logout</a> <h4>&copy;Home Page</h4> </div>


  <!-- /footer -->

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pageChange event, documented [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html).

> This event is triggered after the changePage() request has finished loading the page into the DOM and all page transition animations have completed.